# Count 'Yes' in Specific Columns for Each Row in Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, count, nested-loops

I have a loop going through my data frame to fill a new column based on other column values. I need to identify if there is a 'yes' in more than one column.

Dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("AJ", "DJ", "EJ", "MJ", "CJ"),
                 meds_1=c("yes","yes", "no", "no", "yes"), 
                 meds_2=c("no", "no","no", "yes", "yes"),
                 meds_3=c("no", "no","no", "no", "no"),
                 meds_4=c("no", "no","no", "no", "no"),
                 status=c("Non-stable","Non-stable","stable", "stable", "Non-stable"))

#the new column
df$status_check <- NA
```

The order should go:

If status == 'stable', then status_check = 'stable', else if someone has 'yes' in more than one column that starts with 'meds_', then status_check = 'combo', else 'other'.

The issue is that I'm not sure how to loop over the columns that start with 'meds_', count the number of 'yes' and if it is over 1, then status_check is 'Combo'

My loop so far:

```
#I am not sure what function needs to go into the second ifelse statement.
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 df$status_check<-ifelse(df$status == "stable", "stable",
                            ifelse([some function],"Combo","Other"))
}
```

The results should look like:

```
  name meds_1 meds_2 meds_3 meds_4     status status_check
1   AJ    yes     no     no     no Non-stable        Other
2   DJ    yes     no     no     no Non-stable        Other
3   EJ     no     no     no     no     stable       stable
4   MJ     no    yes     no     no     stable       stable
5   CJ    yes    yes     no     no Non-stable        Combo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can start with `rowSums` to get all rows with >= 2 `yes` in `meds`. `starts_with` is very useful for this use case.
Then a simple `case_when` does the trick.

**Observation** I used the data from the desired output dataframe, as it differs from the original data.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(status_check = rowSums(across(starts_with('meds_'), ~.x == 'yes')),
           status_check = case_when(status == 'stable' ~ 'stable',
                                    status_check >=2   ~ 'combo',
                                    TRUE               ~ "other"))

  name meds_1 meds_2 meds_3 meds_4     status status_check
1   AJ    yes     no     no     no Non-stable        other
2   DJ    yes     no     no     no Non-stable        other
3   EJ     no     no     no     no     stable       stable
4   MJ     no    yes     no     no     stable       stable
5   CJ    yes    yes     no     no Non-stable        combo
```

Comment: I didn't know case_when existed. thanks!

Comment: Whenever you think of using nested `ifelse` s, think of `case_when`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rowSums` to compute the number of `yes` columns for each row. Also, there is no need for a `for` loop.

Note: Your example data differed from the one you posted for your desired result, i.e. there are two `yes` in row 1.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("AJ", "DJ", "EJ", "MJ", "CJ"),
  meds_1 = c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes"),
  meds_2 = c("no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes"),
  meds_3 = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"),
  meds_4 = c("no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes"),
  status = c("Non-stable", "Non-stable", "stable", "stable", "Non-stable")
)

df$status_check <- ifelse(df$status == "stable", "stable", ifelse(rowSums(df[, 2:5] == "yes") > 1, "Combo", "Other"))

df
#>   name meds_1 meds_2 meds_3 meds_4     status status_check
#> 1   AJ    yes     no    yes     no Non-stable        Combo
#> 2   DJ    yes     no     no     no Non-stable        Other
#> 3   EJ     no     no     no     no     stable       stable
#> 4   MJ     no    yes     no    yes     stable       stable
#> 5   CJ    yes    yes     no    yes Non-stable        Combo
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This hard-codes the columns fed to rowSums, and may work only for the sample data. If the OP has more columns named "meds_x", this answer would not be generalizable to that case.